# Soap UI - where are the preferences/settings stored in Windows

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I have Soap UI v5 which the trial has run out and I need to export the preferences, does anyone know where these are stored in Windows? Is it the registry or in a particular folder so I can easily import the same settings on another machine.

I'll also need the indivdual project settings too.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In windows 7 by default preferences are stored in `$USER_HOME/default-soapui-workspace.xml` and `$USER_HOME/soapui-settings.xml`.

`default-soapui-workspace.xml` is for the workspace (project names, where are stored, if they are closed...), looking here you can see also the `xml` path where 
your project data is stored (`testCases`,`testSteps`,`request` contents, `assertions` and so on).

```
<con:soapui-workspace name="Projects" soapui-version="5.0.0" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
  <con:settings/>
  <con:project name="MyProject">C:/Projectes/SOAPUI proj/NT-soapui-suport.xml</con:project>
  ...
```

`soapui-settings.xml` is for your soapui settings and properties configuration like `http settings`, `ssl settings` and so on.

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks - i'll try that out shortly, I presume this contains the projects data as well?

Comment: @Zabs No, project data are stored in separate xmls files. In `<con:project>` values in `default-soapui-workspace.xml` you can see the path for xmls where your project data is stored (testcases, teststep, requests, assertions, and so on).

Comment: thanks i found all the relevant project xml files too using your advice as well

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10:

- `%HOMEPATH%/soapui-settings.xml`
- `%HOMEPATH%/default-soapui-workspace.xml`

Comment: Note: This is basically the same as the accepted answer, except that it uses `%HOMEPATH%` instead of `$USER_HOME`. Since you don't have enough rep to comment yet, I think that this was the best approach to simplify/clarify the path, so here's an upvote.